# PHP, Symfony, Wamp Server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I'm a web developer. So I have imported a production version of PHP project code by using Symfony version 3 framework. I have put the  project in www folder of Wamp Server in localhost.

I've verified if the project is entirely imported and it is. The project contains in a root folder an htaccess file, and in web folder also another htaccess file.I have put the when i launch the project, just a part of the project ressources are uploaded. And i got this error on a the web page :

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>   The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
>   Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

And when I make some modifications on the code, Wamp Server didn't update those modifications.

Comment: Please use paragraphs when writing here. That means that when you come to the edge of the screen, keep typing without pressing Enter. Generally, sentences will automatically wrap on the next line, and you can force a paragraph break (Enter twice) in order to group your sentences into themes. I've edited this time around, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to run the project in production mode or development mode? If you try to run it in production mode, did you cleared the cache before running? Does the cache directory has writing permissions? Are there any database settings that has to be changed to match your environment's values? These are the common issues that can happen, but there are lots of other cases that can come up.

Try to run the project in development mode (eg.: http://localhost/www/your_project_name/web/app_dev.php/ - or whatever your dev file is called) and check what it says - in development mode, the errors are way more verbose than in production mode, obviously.

Comment: I tried to run in production mod and a clear th cache also. And i refreshed the server and web browser. The server updates the changes that i've made in the source code. But i' still have the errors  Oops ! An Error Occurred The server returned a 500 Internal Server Error. Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error ...  And I remarked that one twig file called  index.html.twig is not loaded. And when i tried to connect to the data base in localhost in phpMyAdmin, i got this error : mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045):  Access denied for user.

Comment: This error means that you aren't allowed to connect to the database with this user. I can think about that connection is not allowed from the location that you are trying to connect, only from localhost. Or maybe the user simply does not have granted access to connect to the database. Try to grant permissions for the user from the mysql console, reload the permissions table and then try to connect again.